# How can I view Chromium console log from command line?

Tags: debian, command-line, chrome

I have chromium running on a remote (Debian Linux) machine. It is displaying local content.

I can remotely log on to the machine using SSH for access to the command line. I cannot remotely inspect the console log via GUI.

1. Is there a Chromium console log file?
2. If so, where would it typically be located?
3. If no, is there another way to view Chromium console log output from the command line?

Comment: What is the real question here? "How do I view log files in terminal" or "Where is the chromium log file located"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068090/2072269

Answer (score 5):

Run chromium as follow:

```
chromium --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 &> ~/file.log
```

From ssh:

```
tail -f ~/file.log
```

[How to enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)

Answer (score 3):

On a Raspberry Pi which is Debian based using Buster version 10 I used this command to launch:

```
chromium --enable-logging --v=1
```

Then to find the log file I used:

```
sudo find / -name "chrome*.log"
```

I used this to view the log(the path will likley be different for you):

```
sudo tail -f /rds/home/rds-user/.config/chromium/chrome_debug.log
```

You could just `cat` or `nano` instead of `tail -f`.